# Site Analytics - 'Weekly' checkbox does not reset upon refreshing in Firefox

Tags: bug, firefox, site-analytics

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [Site Analytics](/site-analytics); the Posts graph (usually) opens in the daily view
2. Click the 'Weekly' checkbox, the graph will immediately show the weekly view
3. Refresh the page. The 'Weekly' checkbox will stay checked, but the graph switches back to daily view.
4. Now, to go back to the weekly view you'll have to first uncheck the checkbox and then check it again.

[image]

I can consistently reproduce this issue on Firefox on macOS, on several sites. However, when I try it on Safari, it works normally; after reloading the page, the 'Weekly' checkbox unchecks itself.